# LanmanServerが起動しない（Dockerインストールエラー）

Tags: docker, windows-10

#### 質問内容

Windows１０Proで、LanmanServerを起動させる方法を知りたいです。

#### 背景

ある日PCを立ち上げた後、Docker Desktop for Windowsが立ち上がらなくなり、アンインストールして再インストールしようとしたところ、以下の画面が出ました。

```
Docker Desktop requires the Server service to be enabled.
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

文言を読むに、LanmanServerが立ち上がってないことが原因だと思い、サービスを確認したところ、
想定通り起動していませんでした。

これを立ち上げようと思い、管理者権限で実行したコマンドプロンプトでLanmanServerを立ち上げようとしたところ、
下記のアクセス拒否が発生しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、Administrator権限のユーザで操作しており、
拒否される要因がわかりません。
また、Windowsを触った経験も少ないため、
他にどのような要因が影響しているか掴めない状況です。

誠に恐縮ですが、
ご教授をいただきたく存じます、

Comment: [2.2.xよりlanmanserverは不要になった](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5150#issuecomment-586260197)はず、のようです。ですが依然としてエラーが出た、という報告もあります。現状では原因不明で正式な解決策も判明していないように見えます。ただ、(不要のはずだが)[GUI](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5150#issuecomment-580683869)から設定することで動いた、という報告が散見されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実は私もこの記事拝見してrelease noteを確認したのですが、[ver2.3.0.3ではインストール前のlanmanserverの確認が追加されたようです](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/)。したがって、lanmanserver自体は必要なものだと理解しております。ただ、これが起動できないのですが。。。

Comment: すみません、2.3.0.2ですね